# BinaryFormatter.Deserlize for a Bitmap rases a System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, tcpclient, networkstream, tcpserver, binaryformatter

so ..  am creating a Simple Desktop Viewer application.

but i keep getting this System.outOfMmemoryException when ever i try to de-serialize sent images through the stream.

the sending code :

```
 private Image getScreen() {

        Rectangle bound = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
        Bitmap ScreenShot = new Bitmap(bound.Width,bound.Height,PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb );
        Graphics image = Graphics.FromImage(ScreenShot);
        image.CopyFromScreen(bound.X,bound.Y,0,0,bound.Size,CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
        return ScreenShot;
    }
    private void SendImage() {
        BinaryFormatter binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        binFormatter.Serialize(stream, getScreen());
    }
```

note that the images are sent using a timer that calls the SendImage() once it's started

this is my Recieving Code :

```
 BinaryFormatter binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                Image img = (Image)binFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
                picturebox1.Image=img;
```

so .. whats Wrong?

Comment: "so .. whats Wrong?" You're probably running out of memory. As the error says.

Comment: OK , how can i solve it?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're trying to write some kind of 'remote desktop' program? That's really too broad of a subject to discuss here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: i guess it is , but am not really trying to discuss it am just trying to find out What is wrong with this bit of code , and how to fix it.

Comment: if you happen to know a link i could go to for help i'd appreciate it

Comment: .NET programmers tend to ignore the Dispose() method, they can keep that up for a while.  Until they start playing with Image or Bitmap, a very small .NET wrapper for a large amount of unmanaged memory.  SendImage() needs to use the `using` statement so the return value of getScreen() gets disposed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this caused by a wrong usage of Stream. The code below is working fine:

```
private Image getScreen() {
    Rectangle bound = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
    Bitmap ScreenShot = new Bitmap(bound.Width,bound.Height,PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb );
    Graphics image = Graphics.FromImage(ScreenShot);
    image.CopyFromScreen(bound.X,bound.Y,0,0,bound.Size,CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
    return ScreenShot;
}
private void SendImage(Stream stream) {
    BinaryFormatter binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    binFormatter.Serialize(stream, getScreen());
}

void Main()
{
    byte[] bytes = null;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
        SendImage(ms);
        bytes = ms.ToArray();
    }

    var receivedStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    BinaryFormatter binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    Image img = (Image)binFormatter.Deserialize(receivedStream);
    img.Save("c:\\temp\\test.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, the thing is , The stream am using is a NetworkStream taken from a TCP connection between client and server, i'll edit the question and add the TCP part

Comment: In this case, you need to read all bytes from it, and then deserialize the array of bytes.

Comment: thanks dude, i should'v made clearer earlier , this is part of a chat app  where the user can share their Desktop view after event is triggered, i tride starting the connection with only desktop view and it works it seems to be that the problem is with the stream, how can i "clean" or "reset" it to the state it was straight after connection?

Comment: "in this case, you need to read all bytes from it, and then deserialize the array of bytes" , and How do i do that?